# Playing videos in android by using videoview from remote url

Tags: android, android-videoview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Video Streaming using Video View (video view not showing automatially)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593664/android-video-streaming-using-video-view-video-view-not-showing-automatially)

Am trying to play video by using video view. The url is  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/SpotKan/spotkan%2Fspotkanvideo_11339479677671.mp4?Expires=1339571130&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDYFUTWVEWQSJRDA&Signature=huAPVtuxW3PtjUvT4Cxptnmfch0%3D". Am using the below code

```
    vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(vView);
 Uri video = Uri.parse(vSource);
 vView.setMediaController(mediaController);
 vView.setVideoURI(video);
 vView.start();
```

this shows an error as  D/MediaPlayer(562): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
Please provide any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that your url should be .mp4 or 3gp

Comment: See My Answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593664/android-video-streaming-using-video-view-video-view-not-showing-automatially/7593749#7593749).